# R mutate_if rounding issue

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with a few character columns and many numerical columns. I need to replace all the numerical values in all the columns greater than 1 with 1, without modifying the character columns.
I use mutate_if to achieve my goal but the problem I face is that it's automatically rounding the data and I don't want that. How can I avoid the rounding?
This is my sample code:

```
mtcars$TEXT <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~4.00 * (. > 4))
```

if you print it, you will notice all the values are now either 4 or 0.
I'm really confused and can't figure out why.
Thanks

Comment: use `ifelse`: `mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ifelse(. > 1, 1, .))`

Comment: why you are using 4 ? the question is replacing greater than 1 with 1 but you are doing something else.

Comment: See `pmin` ...........

Comment: @bouncyball your solution works great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Thanks to Gregor Thomas and the feedback of the community:
Here is the edited version:

```
library(dplyr)
# old solution
# mtcars %>%  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~case_when(is.numeric(.) & . > 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ .)))

# new solution implementing the advice of Gregor Thomas and Hong Ooi
mtcars %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), pmin, 1))
```

data:

```
mtcars$TEXT <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~4.00 * (. > 4))
```

Output:

```
                    mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb                TEXT
Mazda RX4             1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  1    1    1           Mazda RX4
Mazda RX4 Wag         1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  1    1    1       Mazda RX4 Wag
Datsun 710            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1          Datsun 710
Hornet 4 Drive        1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1      Hornet 4 Drive
Hornet Sportabout     1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1   Hornet Sportabout
Valiant               1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1             Valiant
Duster 360            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1          Duster 360
Merc 240D             1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1           Merc 240D
Merc 230              1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1            Merc 230
Merc 280              1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1            Merc 280
Merc 280C             1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1           Merc 280C
Merc 450SE            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1          Merc 450SE
Merc 450SL            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1          Merc 450SL
Merc 450SLC           1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1         Merc 450SLC
Cadillac Fleetwood    1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1  Cadillac Fleetwood
Lincoln Continental   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1 Lincoln Continental
Chrysler Imperial     1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1   Chrysler Imperial
Fiat 128              1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1            Fiat 128
Honda Civic           1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1         Honda Civic
Toyota Corolla        1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1      Toyota Corolla
Toyota Corona         1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  0    1    1       Toyota Corona
Dodge Challenger      1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1    Dodge Challenger
AMC Javelin           1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1         AMC Javelin
Camaro Z28            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1          Camaro Z28
Pontiac Firebird      1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  0    1    1    Pontiac Firebird
Fiat X1-9             1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1           Fiat X1-9
Porsche 914-2         1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  1    1    1       Porsche 914-2
Lotus Europa          1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1        Lotus Europa
Ford Pantera L        1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  1    1    1      Ford Pantera L
Ferrari Dino          1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  1    1    1        Ferrari Dino
Maserati Bora         1   1    1  1    1  1    1  0  1    1    1       Maserati Bora
Volvo 142E            1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1          Volvo 142E
```

Comment: I think the solution above still has the same issue. Where the data is not satisfying the condition is set equal to 0. You see it?

Comment: Do you mean `TRUE ~ .` ? Please see my edit.

Comment: Your output values are all either 0 or 1. The solution shared above by @bouncyball does exactly what I need: mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ifelse(. > 1, 1, .)).
Many thanks for your help TarJae

Comment: Please use `mutate_across()` These helpers have been deprecated: `mutate_if.(.df, .predicate, .funs, ..., .by = NULL); mutate_at.(.df, .vars, .funs, ..., .by = NULL); mutate_all.(.df, .funs, ..., .by = NULL)`. The solution of bouncyball gives the same output as my edited version. You are welcome!

Comment: Since you have `where(is.numeric)`, the `is.numeric(.)` check inside `case_when` is redundant. You can simplify a little to `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~case_when(. > 1 ~ 1,TRUE ~ .)))`, or taking the `pmin` advice simplify a lot to `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), pmin, 1))`

Comment: @TarJae thanks for your help so far, I appreciate you looking into this. your last solution works as well as the one shared by Gregor Thomas

Comment: Thank you all. Especially Gregor Thomas and Hong Ooi. I have implemented the suggestions. Please see my edit. For me it is the best way to learn and evolve!!